# How to integrate the Scala Squeryl ORB with play 2.0 framework?

Tags: playframework, squeryl

I am trying to use Squeryl ORB with play 2.0 framework, but when calling `DB.getConnection()` during initialization I get:

> BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path ' - could not find datasource for defaultdb': Token not allowed in path expression:  '-' (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)

The database configuration looks like this (conf/application.conf):

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=postgres&password=postgres"
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.jndiName=defaultdb
```

And the initializing:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {

    SessionFactory.externalTransactionManagementAdapter = Some(() => 
        Some(new Session(
          DB.getConnection("defaultdb", true),
          new PostgreSqlAdapter)))
    ...
```

Is this the right way to do it? Is it correct to use the `db.default.jndiName` config value as parameter value to `DB.getConnection()`?

Or should it be done like this?:

```
  SessionFactory.concreteFactory = Some(() =>
    Session.create(
      java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://..."),
      new PostgreSqlAdapter))
```

This works, but then I am not able to use the squeryl query objects in the template for iteration, which I hoped would be possible with `externalTransactionManagementAdapter`.

### Update:

I corrected to the following: `DB.getConnection("default", true)` and removed the `db.default.jndiName` config.
With this I am able to get and use a connection, but the second time `getConnection()` is called, it throws `SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.`

### Update 2:

I haven't managed to use `externalTransactionManagementAdapter`, but `concreteFactory` works well - as described below.

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive regarding what you're trying to accomplish?  I'm not very familiar with Play or what a "template for iteration" would mean.  The externalTransactionManagementAdapter is for situations where SQL transactions will be handled outside of Squeryl (not with transaction{} / inTransaction{} blocks).  I can't tell from your question whether it fits your need.

Comment: If I understand "play" correctly, it should be able to handle the SQL transactions for me. In that case, I should be able to iterate over a squeryl query outside a transaction block, for instance when rendering html in a play template, right? The described error is probably more a play-issue than squeryl, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next works for me:

```
import play.db.DB 
import play.api.Application 
import play.api.GlobalSettings 
import org.squeryl._ 
import org.squeryl.adapters._
```

....

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings
{

override def onStart(app:Application):Unit =
{
 SessionFactory.concreteFactory = Some(
      () => Session.create(DB.getDataSource().getConnection(),
                           dbAdapter)
 );
}

override def onStop(app:Application):Unit =
{
}

val dbAdapter = new PostgreSqlAdapter();

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed to use this code, but I still get `SQLException: Timed out...` as described in the update above. Are you using the connections in `transaction` blocks? Could you maybe give a simple example of a select and the context it's used in?

Comment: This exception is throwed by BoneCP  when all connections are acquired    and none is released.  The reason can vary from application error (not closing jdbc connections at all ; using transaction instead inTransaction and nesting one blocks more than pool size,  loop with connection grabbing inside; etc)

Comment: So, better enable trace in log [minimal - application.log=TRACE in application.conf], more detailed -- enable trace specially for "com.jolbox.bonecp" logger ]  and look for 'Check in connection' and Check out connection'  messages in log.

Comment: For every http request (doing a single db-select) 17 connections were checked out and only one returned. The problem was my usage of `externalTransactionManagementAdapter` - and the fact that play had to be restarted manually when changing SessionFactory. So when using `concreteFactory` it does work, but it demands a `transaction` block around the view call when the squeryl query is used in the view. I had hoped that play would manage transactions for me by using `externalTransactionManagementAdapter`, but I guess I would still have to tell squeryl to "return" the connection somehow...

Comment: I personally use concreteFactory, I would advise against using externalTransactionManagementAdapter with Play, as it is made for frameworks that manage the commmit for you (typically on a per web request mode, like Lift). Setting concreteFactory does mean that you need to explicitely declare transaction {} or inTransaction {}. Personally I prefer explicit transaction.